# Eclipse don't save editor annotations settings

Tags: eclipse

I try to use the dark theme of Eclipse, but some text highlighting makes the texts unreadable.

 So I edited settings here

[image]

But it is gone after restarting eclipse. I try to remove every read-only property from files in the workspace an installation dir. But without success.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the same and it is working for me (after restart):

[image: Error annotation blue dashed box]

What is your Eclipse version? My Help > About says:

```
Spring Tool Suite 

Version: 3.7.1.RELEASE
Build Id: 201510041213
Platform: Eclipse Mars.1 (4.5.1)

Copyright (c) 2007 - 2015 Pivotal Software, Inc.
All rights reserved. Visit http://spring.io/tools/sts

This product includes software developed by the
Apache Software Foundation http://www.apache.org
```

Comment: I uninstalled eclipe :) It was the latest version at 12.1.2015